# Using a button to switch between tabs in Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, tabs, vba

How do I create a VBA macro to switch between pages in a tab control on a form in Access? I would think the code would be simple, but I haven't been able to find anything clear or definitive online. These are the code samples I've tried so far:

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()
TabControl.Value = (TabCtl0.Value + 1) Mod TabControl.Pages.Count
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
Me.Tab2.SetFocus
End Sub
```

But I wonder if something more complicated is needed. The button and the tabs are separate (button is not on the tab itself), as shown in the image:

[image: Form Navigation Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the macro builder, you can also use "go to control"

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an old question, but for the benefit of anyone else that stumbles upon it:

The first example you give in the ones you've tried should work, but has a bug in it. The code refers to both TabControl and TabCtl0, and I think it should be just one or the other.

Assuming your button is called Command9, as in the image, and your tab control is called TabControl, the following should work:

```
Private Sub Command9_Click()
  TabControl.Value = (TabControl.Value + 1) Mod TabControl.Pages.Count
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've inadvertently referred to `TabControl` when you mean to refer to `TabCtl0`.

You can make the references briefer by using a `With..End With` statement

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()
  With Me.TabCtl0
    .Value = (.Value + 1) Mod .Pages.Count
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a navigation control form, so I intentionally named it TabControl. Even after renaming the tabs NavigationButton1 and 2 respectively and referencing NavigationButton1 in the code (With.Me.NavigationButton1), I still get "Method or data member not found" on the second instance of .Value.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply switch between the tabs?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OtN2DSg-cAU

That should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: I know about tab control, but we want a macro that will run through multiple tabs, one tab at a time, when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Me.TabControlName.Pages.Item("PageName").SetFocus
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. On the On click event of a button

Me.tabname.SetFocus

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).